# Show specific presenter instance to flex panel gwt mvp

Tags: model-view-controller, gwt, instance, presenter

I'm still learning GWT, yet already have to face some kind of challenge for a work I have to do. Can't show any specific code so I'll try to explain it well.

Here's the situation: A certain class "Navigator" creates and save the Presenter instances of my architecture to allow reusing them. There is a method `show()` inside that same class that actually displays the view  related but that system only works full screen by calling `RootPanel.get()`.

What i'd like to do is showing that presenter instance's view inside of a flex panel element declared in a class `myView` (related to a class `myPresenter`) that basically uses Flex Panel to structure it's content.

To make it maybe more clear:

```
class myView{
...

    flexPanel.setWidget(firstWIdget)      
    flexPanel.setWidget(secondWidget) //secondWidget to be replaced by a "thirdWidget"

...
}
```

I'd like the `secondWidget` to be replaced by another one, let's call it `thirdWidget`, that consists of a specific presenter instance's view.

To resume, I'd like my presenter instance's view to not go full screen but only occupy a certain area of the screen.

The displaying is managed almost entirely programmatically, means very limited use of css files and no use at all of xml ui files.

How can I manage this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a SimplePanel as a container for your views returned by your Navigation class instead of adding them directly to root panel, and use that instance of SimplePanel where ever you want.